# При вводе строки в консоль, в строку записывается Null

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Кто ты есть?");
string? str = Console.ReadLine();
if (str.ToLower() == "маша")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Привет, Маша");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Привет {str}");
}
```

Привет всем.
Супер просто код. При вводе русского текста "Никита, Петя, Вася". В str записывается Null.

Прочитал все что можно, но не понимаю в чем дело.
P.s Кодировка UTF-8. Null diseble делать тоже пробовал

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести, этот код работает. Ввожу русский текст. Просто создал новый .NET 6 проект, вставил ваш код и он работает. Никаких кодировок не менял, ничего больше не делал. Вообще нормально работающий ReadLine никогда не вернет null при вводе из консоли с клавиатуры. Проблема не в коде.

Comment: При запуске программы выдает предупреждение warning CS8602.
За место вывода в консоль строки, по сути выдает пустоту.
Вывод получается: Привет
Может ли дело быть в том, что у меня стоит .NET 7?

Comment: Вероятно, вы просто жмёте <Enter> - в итоге вводится пустая строка. Это не null.

Comment: Предупреждение на этапе компиляции никак не связано с поведением в рантайме.

Comment: Нет, именно, я ввожу имя. Но на вывод подается только "Привет ".
Немного прояснилось, проблема в русском тексте. Латиница выводится как положено.

Comment: То что выводится пустое, это далеко не значит что в переменную попадает null. Грубо говоря, 3 пробела - это тоже выглядит как пустое. Проверьте `Console.WriteLine(Console.OutputEncoding.EncodingName);`, у меня выводит `Codepage - 866`. Второе, что следует проверить, это выбранный шрифт для отображения текста в консоли, он должен поддерживать кириллицу. Дело точно не в версии .NET. Еще так же можно проверить `Console.InputEncoding.EncodingName`, у меня она тоже 866.

Comment: **Console.WriteLine(Console.OutputEncoding.EncodingName);** -  Unicode (UTF-8).
По поводу шрифтов стоит **Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace**.
При вводе команды **Console.InputEncoding.EncodingName** - тоже Unicode (UTF-8).

Comment: Все решилось, дело было в версии .NET.